# PHP fetched decimal value echo's only first digit

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, decimal

I am fetching prices from my database by article_no. I am sending the article via ajax to php:

```
var comps_gehaz = {};
comps_gehaz['articleNumbers'] = 38292783;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",

    url: "php/gehaz.php",
    data: {gehaz_json_data: JSON.stringify(comps_gehaz)},
    dataType: "text",

    success: function (msg, string, jpXHR) {

        if(msg) {
            $('#gehaz_priceTag').html(msg);
        } else {
            console.log('Something else went wrong.');
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
    }
});
```

My table structure in MySQL is:

...
"price" -> decimal(10,2)
"articleNo" -> BIGINT
...

PHP:

```
$gehaz_json_data = $_POST['gehaz_json_data'];
$obj = json_decode($gehaz_json_data, true);

$articleNumber = $obj['articleNumber'];

$getMoney = "SELECT price FROM Articles WHERE articleNo = '$articleNumber'";

if (mysqli_query($db_link, $getMoney)) {
    $result_price = mysqli_query($db_link, $getMoney);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_price)) {
        $list_price_notFormat = $row['price'];
    }
    echo $list_price_notFormat;
}
```

If the price value is 345.56, it displays it correct. But if it is a bigger than thousand like 3036.47, it only echo the first digit '3'.

Comment: `$list_price_notFormat = (float)$row['price'];`  or `$list_price_notFormat = (double)$row['price'];`

Comment: Can you add some values of db here? Is articleNo is P.K. ?

Comment: @Anant didnt work

Comment: @kamal... the value for price is e.g. 234.56 or 3736.43

Comment: Okay but I am asking *Is articleNo is P.K.?* because if it is not then you might be getting only 3 due to last value (as 3) for that articleNo in db

Comment: do `$row['price'];` inside `while` and see it is printing `3736.43` or `3` only?

Comment: its not the primary key

Comment: okay then your should check all values related to that Article, probably your last value is '3' that's why you're getting it. Try to echo inside while loop and you'll get that

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem was.

the values in my database are set automatically with javascript/node.js. I am reading the values from a Excel file and save them in my MySQL-table. before putting them in the column with datatype 'Decimal 10,2', I had to parse the value from my Excel-Sheet for example '1.253,64' to String so I can replace the '.' by '' end ',' by '.', so it looks like 1253.64

I assume that is the reason why it only reads the first digit.

Should I change the datatype from decimal to float or is there a better way for saving prices in mysql?

Comment: I think you should add this info in your Question. This is not right way to ask question in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out how to export the *number*, not the *string* from Excel.  You are stumbling over "locale" issues with "thousands separator".